# Progress bar with background worker Part 2

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I just can't see what I am doing wrong here, since I have implemented a progress bar into my background worker it no longer only runs the once (in some cases I have seen the coding within the foor loop run 6 times)

My coding:-

```
My progress bar max value is set to 10.

‘ BGWorker Do Work Event
            For i As Integer = 1 To 2
‘ Run code 1
Next

            For i As Integer = 2 To 3
‘ Run code 2
Next


            For i As Integer = 3 To 4
‘ Run code 3
Next

            For i As Integer = 4 To 5
‘ Run code 4
Next

            For i As Integer = 5 To 6
‘ Run code 5 
Next

            For i As Integer = 6 To 8
‘ Run code 6
Next

            For i As Integer = 8 To 9
‘ Run code 7
Next

‘ BGWorker Progress changed event
            Me.Progressbar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
            Me.label1.Text = String.Format("{0} % Completed", e.ProgressPercentage * 10)
```

I would really appreciate any help as I just cant see why my coding within the loops should not only run the once.

Comment: You're not showing your code for calling report progress, etc.  When you say " I have seen the coding within the foor loop run 6 times)", do you mean in the debugger? in the progress bar? where?

Comment: Are you reporting the progress?  Those Next For you post make no sense to me.  Post your background worker.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a `For - Loop 1 to 2` will run two times.  Same for `3 to 4`, `5 to 6`.

Your original code was just:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 2
  ‘ Run code 1
Next

For i As Integer = 3 To 4
  ‘ Run code 2
Next
```

which did the same thing.

But it sounds like you don't need the `For - Loops` at all if all you are doing is running the code once.  If there are ten steps to your background worker, then try calling the ten updates:

```
‘ Run code 1
BGWorker.ReportProgress(1)

‘ Run code 2
BGWorker.ReportProgress(2)

‘ Run code 3
BGWorker.ReportProgress(3)

‘ etc
```

Comment: Hi Lars, one more thing if I was to have BGWorker.ReportProgress(1) and then after the next coding BGWorker.ReportProgress(3) would that mean that coding is 20% rather than 10% completed?

Comment: @JackSparrow You can pass any number you want.  It's your number.  From what I can figure out from your code, you seem to have to run 10 different code snippets, so if your ProgressBar is set for a maximum of 10, it would make sense by the time you run code snippet #10, you report the progress with a value of 10, to match your ProgressBar's maximum value.  If you had to run 15 different code snippets, then you would set the ProgressBar maximum value to 15, and keep reporting progress 1 to 15.